# Не блокируемые окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим, есть окно, которое может создавать, как модальные окна, так и обычные окна.

Понятное дело, что если создается модальное окно, то все остальные окна перестают работать.

Можно ли сделать некоторые отдельные окна иммунными к модальным? Т.е что бы они не блокировались.

У меня такие мысли:

1. Отказаться вообще от модальных окон и в этом случае придется самому эмулировать эту функциональность, блокируя отдельные формы и все такое...
2. Наверное, отдельные окна можно создавать отдельных потоках, который будет жить пока окно не убито.

Что из этого наиболее верное или есть что-то более удобное?

Comment: Если вы хотите заблокировать окно, но при этом не блокировать другие окна, используйте popup

Comment: *Отказаться вообще от модальных окон* и показывать диалоги внутри окна, к которому этот диалог относится

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну так одно другому не мешает, зачем совсем от модальных окон отказываться то